# Shuffle array losing data

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have an array and when I check this with `print_r` the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => metaalboutique.jpg [1] => asc.jpg [2] => thure.jpg [3] => stegge.jpg [4] => aws.jpg [5] => rsw.jpg [6] => pmm.jpg )
```

I want the export to be shuffled so I use `shuffle()` but when I check the output with `print_r` now I only see `1` as output.

```
$portfolio = array
  (
    'thure.jpg',
    'rsw.jpg',
    'pmm.jpg',
    'asc.jpg',
    'stegge.jpg',
    'metaalboutique.jpg',
    'aws.jpg'
  );

$shuffled_portfolio = shuffle($portfolio);
print_r($portfolio);
print_r($shuffled_portfolio);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) shuffles an array **in place** and returns a boolean to indicate if the shuffling succeeded (`TRUE`) or not (`FALSE`):

```
$portfolio = array
  (
    'thure.jpg',
    'rsw.jpg',
    'pmm.jpg',
    'asc.jpg',
    'stegge.jpg',
    'metaalboutique.jpg',
    'aws.jpg'
  );
print_r($portfolio);

$success = shuffle($portfolio);
if ($success) {
    # $portfolio is now shuffled
    print_r($portfolio);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP `shuffle` function returns boolean value.

> shuffle — Shuffle an array
>
> bool shuffle ( array &$array )

&$array - the `&` sign means you are passing a reference of an array in that function.

***Return Values***

> Returns TRUE (1) on success or FALSE(0) on failure.